# creating .graphml tree diagram from nested list

Tags: binary-tree, diagram, graphviz, dot, graphml

I am desperately looking for a solution to create a nice binary tree diagram. It is crucial that incomplete nodes have distinguishable edges (if any).

I failed to produce the desired result with .dot, because I know of no way to order nodes. I don't mind, importing a file to yEd or another editor. However, I want to be able to generate data very easily with little syntax.

What I am aiming at is a tool which generates e.g. a .graphml format from minimalistic data, such as (A (B1 C1 C2) B2), where A is the root label, B1 the root's left child with another two children. A similar complexity as .dot or .tgf would be of course tolerable, but I want to avoid writing a compiler myself for generating the .graphml.

Any ideas appreciated.

Markus R.

Comment: What do you mean by _This works in .dot only if empty nodes are used_ ?

Comment: That is, I have to use invisible virtual nodes(leafs) to direct an edge.

Comment: In visualizing the graph, why are virtual nodes to be avoided?

Comment: I discovered, that using dot, even virtual nodes do not guarantee absence of vertical edges. If virtual nodes with graphml did the job, I would be happy. (Yet to find out).

Answer (score 1):

The data that you supplied is more-or-less an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexp).  Given that this is the format that you want to ingest, pyparsing (a Python module) has an [s-expression parser](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/sexpParser.py).

You'll also need a graph library.  I use [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) for most of my work.  With the pyparsing s-expression parser and networkx, the following code ingests the data and creates a tree as a digraph:

```py
import networkx as nx

def build(g, X):
    if isinstance(X, list):
        parent = X[0]
        g.add_node(parent)
        for branch in X[1:]:
            child = build(g, branch)
            g.add_edge(parent, child)

        return parent

    if isinstance(X, basestring):
        g.add_node(X)
        return X

#-- The sexp parser is constructed by the code example at...
#-- http://http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/sexpParser.py
sexpr = sexp.parseString("(A (B1 C1 C2) B2)", parseAll = True)

#-- Get the parsing results as a list of component lists.
nested = sexpr.asList( )

#-- Construct an empty digraph.
dig = nx.DiGraph( )

#-- build the tree
for component in nested:
    build(dig, component)

#-- Write out the tree as a graphml file.
nx.write_graphml(dig, 'tree.graphml', prettyprint = True)
```

To test this, I also wrote the tree as a .dot file and used graphviz to create the following image:

[image: (graphviz output of tree)]

networkx is a good graph library and you can write additional code that walks over your tree to tag edges or nodes with additional metadata, if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the networkx library. However, the result is not exactly what I need. In your example, if you remove, let's say C2, then in the generated new image, you will have a vertical line from B1 to C1, and hence no longer any indication that C1 is a right child (and B1 has no left child). What I need is an image, which maintains that structure. Regardless, the parser is very useful.

Comment: @MarkusRother if "(A (B1 C1 C2) B2)" describes the present tree, can you supply a similar nested structure for the case where C2 is removed?  If the new nested structure were represented as "(A (B1 C1) B2)" -- how do we distinguish that C1 is the right child of B1 rather than the left child?

Comment: @MarkusRother from reading your previous comment the word "vertical" stood out, and in conjunction with your comment to your question " invisible virtual nodes(leafs) to direct an edge", is the essence of your question one of generating GraphML from a nested structure, or is it the layout and visualization of (possibly) incomplete trees?

Comment: I guess the latter - visualization. Sorry, if I did not point that out sufficiently clearly. To my understanding, a visualization of a binary(!) tree must always be obvious. There are only left or right edges in a binary tree, and any visualization of a binary tree with vertical edges is flawed, because it lacks that information.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing